# Form values not being passed to controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

My Controller Method:

```
 [HttpGet]
    public  ActionResult NewInventory()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<ActionResult> NewInventory(string bookID, string ttlin, string lowin, string Outnow)
    {
       // test values passed, etc.....
    }
```

So far only the "lowin" value is being passed correctly. All the other values are set to "0" (I believe due to the datatypes being set to "not null" in SQL DB). Why is this?

I assume because only one value is passed correctly and no exceptions are thrown, then the view page code is missing the other the fields to pass.

View Code :

```
 @model LibraryMS.Inventory

@{
ViewBag.Title = "newinventory";
 }

<h2>newinventory</h2>

 @using (Html.BeginForm("NewInventory","BookInfo", FormMethod.Post)) 
 {
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()

<div class="form-horizontal">
    <h4>Inventory</h4>
    <hr />
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.BookID, "BookID", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.BookID, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.BookID, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.TotalIn, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.TotalIn, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.TotalIn, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.LowIn, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.LowIn, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.LowIn, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Out, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Out, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Out, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
 }

 <div>
 @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
 </div>
```

By looking, the values are being passed.

Comment: post your form code and if you could post your Get method for that NewInventory form.

Comment: Hi Luv2Learn! Would you mind please posting your View? I've ran into this issue quite a few times due to the name tag in my html not being correct for how ASP.Net convert's form data into your model.

Comment: Made changes to the question to show View code and Get method for view page.

Answer (score -1):

Turns out that the controller method's parameters needs to be spelled the same as what is going to be passed to it. For example:

With the autogenerated form using html helper @Beginform, all the fields are present. But the parameters in the controller method are not the same as the inventory's class fields.

```
public partial class Inventory
{
    public string BookID { get; set; }
    public short TotalIn { get; set; }
    public short LowIn { get; set; }
    public short Out { get; set; }

    public virtual BookInfo BookInfo { get; set; }
}
```

Compared to the paramters:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<ActionResult> NewInventory(string bookID, string ttlin, string lowin, string Outnow)
{
   // test values passed, etc.....
}
```

The fix was to ofcoarse make the params the same, capitalization does not matter.

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<ActionResult> NewInventory(string bookID, string totalin, string lowin, string Out)
{
   // test values passed, etc.....
}
```

It was a simple mistake but took me some time to figure this out. Hopefully this helped someone else!

Comment: You should not expect each property of the model but rather the Model itself. This is very bad coding and does not follow any ASP.NET MVC convention

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto Can you provide a link to where I can read up on that?

Comment: Sure, look [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/implementing-basic-crud-functionality-with-the-entity-framework-in-asp-net-mvc-application), section "Update the Create Page" and onwards

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto , Thanks, I was actually focusing on doing a simple Library System with basic functionality but what you've pointed is important to practice!